# Binding Popup to an Easy Button in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have added an easy button to my map.

```
var info = L.easyButton('glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign')
```

Now I have to bind a popup to this button. I am trying this but it doesn't work.

```
info.bindPopup("Hello").openPopup();
```

Please suggest something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the README in the Github repository:

```
var helloPopup = L.popup().setContent('Hello World!');

L.easyButton('fa-globe', function(btn, map){
    helloPopup.setLatLng(map.getCenter()).openOn(map);
}).addTo(map);
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/sSSHH4?p=preview

README: https://github.com/cliffcloud/Leaflet.EasyButton#boilerplatecopy-paste

Documentation: http://danielmontague.com/projects/easyButton.js/v1/examples/

Comment: I don't want to display it on a specific lat lng. I want it to popup along with the button. I want to display some information in it.

Comment: You're just mentioning this now? Your question is "Now I have to bind a popup to this button." That what my answer does. You're changing the question. Perhaps next time put some thought into your question so that when people take time and effort to answer it they have all the facts. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I understand where you are coming from. You want a description to 'pop up' next to the button on hover. The developers for easy-button call this a Title. Here ya go:

```
L.easyButton('fa-thumbs-up', function(btn, map){
  // button actions
}, 'title for the button');
```